# Join multiple tables,pivot table using Laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

Below is my table charity,its type,member,member designations  now i want result as for particular charity all members of charity with its designation and type of charity in array.

```
Charity
---------------------
id      name        |
---------------------
1       Xcharity    |
2       ycharity    |
---------------------

Charity_type
---------------------
id      name        |
---------------------
1       Masjid      |
2       Mandir      |
3       Madresha    |
---------------------

Designations
---------------------
id      name        |
---------------------
1       Trusty      |
2       President   |
3       Member      |
---------------------

Members
-----------------------------
id      name    charity_id  |
-----------------------------
1       nilesh      1       |
2       Khyati      2       |
-----------------------------   

Charitytype_designation_member
----------------------------------------------------- 
charitytype_id      designation_id      member_id   |
-----------------------------------------------------
    1                   1                   1       |
    2                   2                   1       |
    2                   3                   2       |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

i want array as below charity detail and its member with member are from which charity type and his designation for particular charity type.

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Xcharity
    [members] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => nilesh                    
                    [charity_id] => 2
                    [charity_type] => Masjid
                    [designation] => Trusty                    
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Can you please show your model relationship.

Comment: What do your model relationships look like? The current code you have doesn't help anyone answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$contracts = Charity::with(['members' => function($member_model) {
                    $member_model->select('Members.id', 'Members.name', 'Members.charity_id', 'Charity_type.name as charity_type', 'Designations.name as designation')
                            ->join('Charitytype_designation_member', 'Charitytype_designation_member.member_id', '=', 'Members.id')
                            ->join('Designations', 'Charitytype_designation_member.designation_id', '=', 'Designations.id')
                            ->join('Charity_type', 'Charitytype_designation_member.charitytype_id ', '=', 'Charity_type.id');
                }])->get();
```

I assume `members` relationship in your charity model.

I hope it's help you